# Why JavaScript Not Execute?

Tags: javascript

my javascript won't work I tried everything 
here is the example

```js
function prep2() {
  if (f1.c1.value, f1.a1.value, f1.t1.value != "") {
    var character = f1.c1.value;
    var age = f1.a1.value;
    var thing = f1.t1.value;
    document.getElementByid("lolo").innerHTML = "hi my name is " + character + ", i am " + age + " years old. and i love " + thing;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Story Maker</h1>
  <form name="f1">
    Character <input type="text" name="c1"><br><br> Age&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
    <input type="number" name="a1"><br><br> Favourite <input type="text" name="t1"><br><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="prep2()" value="sumbit">
    <h1>Story:</h1><br>
    <p id="lolo"></p>
  </form>
</body>
```

_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________--

Comment: you are still aware of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)?

Comment: Try `document.getElementById` with an upper case `I`

Comment: `if (f1.c1.value != "" && f1.a1.value != "" && f1.t1.value != "") {`

Comment: I would like to clarify that there's pointy and then there's Pointy

Comment: @Pointy lets just stay on point ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your code had `document.getElementByid` instead of `document.getElementById`.

The below code seems to be working:

```js
function prep2() {
  if (f1.c1.value, f1.a1.value, f1.t1.value != "") {
    var character = f1.c1.value;
    var age = f1.a1.value;
    var thing = f1.t1.value;
    document.getElementById("lolo").innerHTML = "hi my name is " + character + ", i am " + age + " years old. and i love " + thing;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Story Maker</h1>
  <form name="f1">
    Character <input type="text" name="c1"><br><br> Age&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
    <input type="number" name="a1"><br><br> Favourite <input type="text" name="t1"><br><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="prep2()" value="Submit">
    <h1>Story:</h1><br>
    <p id="lolo"></p>
  </form>
</body>
```